# React JS change component style on changing another component's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I am new to react js and I am trying to build an app using it to show the shortest bath, so I defined a graph as a class component containing nodes, every node is also a class component returns an object {isVisited, parent, ...}, and my algorithms must run on this graph. on the other hand I defined components to view the nodes. Now the problem is that I want to restyle the viewed nodes when the graph nodes get visited for example.
Note: I tried to solve this problem by using a reference to the div that view a node in the graph nodes, but this way I am making the functional part and the view part intersect, is there any other way like a custom event where the graph node starts is and the view nodes listen to, or something else solves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

if you want a component to perform an action (like change style) whenever a different component changes state you need to somehow add that state as a prop to the first component.

For example, this is a button component that, when pressed, will change the background color of a different component (box):

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const Box = () => {
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState('red');
  return(
    <div style={{backgroundColor: backgroundColor}}>
      <Button setBackgroundColor={setBackgroundColor} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Button = ({setBackgroundColor}) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={()=>{setBackgroundColor('blue')}}>
      <p>Click me to change the color!</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or at least something like this...